# Level system based off points

Tags: python

I'm trying to make a level system based off of points, but it's kinda getting too long of a code. If you can help me make it smaller I really would appreciated it. To describe what it's suppose to do is get the points and to see what level they are at and if they level up it will tell how many times they level and what level they are at now. I want it to go up to 100 and get harder to level up when getting higher up.. Here's what I have so far:

```
 def pointLevel(name):
    point = Point.dPoint[name]
    points, lvl = int(point), int(lvl)
    if points < 500:
      lvl = 1
    elif points < 1500:
      lvl = 2
    elif points < 2500:
      lvl = 3
    elif points < 5000:
      lvl = 4
    elif points < 10000:
      lvl = 5
    elif points < 15000:
      lvl = 6
    elif points < 20000:
      lvl = 7
    elif points < 30000:
      lvl = 8
    elif points < 50000:
      lvl = 9
    elif points < 100000:
      lvl = 10
    elif points < 250000:
      lvl = 11
    notes.store("levels", user.name, "You have leveled up. You are now level "+str(lvl)+"!", int(time.time()))
```

Comment: The first thing you could think about is to make a function - mathematical first, then in code - that represents your level progression. Something like `lvl = points / 500` and work from there. That should reduce the number of `elif`s you need.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just to shorten your code you can save levels as a list and then count how many levels user have passed by comparing points to the level splits:

```
levels = [100, 200, 300, 400, 500]
lvl = len([x for x in levels if points > x])
```

I wouldn't worry about the speed here, but using generator could be considered as a better practice (or not, a matter of taste in this case):

```
lvl = sum(1 for x in levels if points > x)
```

Comment: That's pretty awesome. That should help me out a lot. Thank you very much.

Comment: Could you give an example of how this would work please for the lvl = sum part of it.

Comment: @user3230748 what do you mean? The code above just works, all you need is define your levels and pass the number of points for a particular user to `points` variable...

Comment: If you mean generator expression, it counts the levels which are smaller than `points` by summing 1's. If points is larger than particular level, it adds 1 (same as counting, right?).

Comment: Yeah. Thats correct. I'm was just trying figure out how that part worked xD

Answer (score 2):

The bisect module is good for finding 'which item in this list is in the right range'.  It returns the index number of upper end of the range your value falls into. For example

```
import bisect

exp_level = [100,200,300,400,500]  # bisect lists need to be sorted
level = bisect.bisect(exp_level, 127)   # = 1
```

In that example bisect.bisect would return "1", since index 1 (that is, 200) is the next item up in the list.

Comment: Does bisect come with python when downloading it or would I have to get it?

Answer (score 1):

If you find yourself repeating the same/similar code <strike>over and over again</strike> more than twice, it's a good sign that you need to use a *loop*:

```
xp_levels = [500, 1500, 2500, 5000, 10000, 15000, 20000, 30000, 50000, 100000, 250000]

def pointLevel(name):
    points = int(Point.dPoint[name])

    level = -1
    for index, xp in enumerate(xp_levels):
        if points < xp:
            level = index
            break
```

Answer (score -1):

To elaborate a bit on @sashkello, here is a function that takes in the points as an integer, and spits out the level:

```
def getLevel(points):
    levels=[500,1500,2500,5000,10000,15000,20000,30000,50000,100000,250000]
    lvl = len([x for x in levels if points > x])
    return lvl
```

Comment: Edited it before your answer... Don't see why integer would matter here.