# I need to shorten this its too long and is noobish

Tags: python

```
        if hp < 250 and lvl == 1:
            hp=250
        elif hp < 500 and lvl == 2:
            hp=500
        elif hp < 750 and lvl == 3:
            hp=750
        elif hp < 1000 and lvl == 4:
            hp=1000
        elif hp < 1250 and lvl == 5:
            hp=1250
        elif hp < 1500 and lvl == 6:
            hp=1500
        elif hp < 1750 and lvl == 7:
            hp=1750
        elif hp < 2000 and lvl == 8:
            hp=2000
        elif hp < 2250 and lvl == 9:
            hp=2250
        elif hp < 2500 and lvl == 10:
            hp=2500
        elif hp < 2750 and lvl == 11:
            hp=2750
        elif hp < 3000 and lvl == 12:
            hp=3000
        elif hp < 3250 and lvl == 13:
            hp=3250
        elif hp < 3500 and lvl == 14:
            hp=3500
        elif hp < 3750 and lvl == 15:
            hp=3750
        elif hp < 4000 and lvl == 16:
            hp=4000
        elif hp < 4250 and lvl == 17:
            hp=4250
        elif hp < 4500 and lvl == 18:
            hp=4500
        elif hp < 4750 and lvl == 19:
            hp=4750
        elif hp < 5000 and lvl == 20:
            hp=5000
        elif hp < 5250 and lvl == 21:
            hp=5250
        elif hp < 5500 and lvl == 22:
            hp=5500
        elif hp < 5750 and lvl == 23:
            hp=5750
        elif hp < 6000 and lvl == 24:
            hp=6000
        elif hp < 6250 and lvl == 25:
            hp=6250
        elif hp < 6500 and lvl == 26:
            hp=6500
        elif hp < 6750 and lvl == 27:
            hp=6750
        elif hp < 7000 and lvl == 28:
            hp=7000
        elif hp < 7250 and lvl == 29:
            hp=7250
        elif hp < 7500 and lvl == 30:
            hp=7500
        elif hp < 7750 and lvl == 31:
            hp=7750
        elif hp < 8000 and lvl == 32:
            hp=8000
        elif hp < 8250 and lvl == 33:
            hp=8250
        elif hp < 8500 and lvl == 34:
            hp=8500
        elif hp < 8750 and lvl == 35:
            hp=8750
        elif hp < 9000 and lvl == 36:
            hp=9000
        elif hp < 9250 and lvl == 37:
            hp=9250
        elif hp < 9500 and lvl == 38:
            hp=9500
        elif hp < 9750 and lvl == 39:
            hp=9750
        elif hp < 10000 and lvl == 40:
            hp=10000
        elif hp < 10250 and lvl == 41:
            hp=10250
        elif hp < 10500 and lvl == 42:
            hp=10500
        elif hp < 10750 and lvl == 43:
            hp=10750
        elif hp < 11000 and lvl == 44:
            hp=11000
        elif hp < 11250 and lvl == 45:
            hp=11250
        elif hp < 11500 and lvl == 46:
            hp=11500
        elif hp < 11750 and lvl == 47:
            hp=11750
        elif hp < 12000 and lvl == 48:
            hp=12000
        elif hp < 12250 and lvl == 49:
            hp=12250
        elif hp < 12500 and lvl == 50:
            hp=12500
        elif hp < 12750 and lvl == 51:
            hp=12750
        elif hp < 13000 and lvl == 52:
            hp=13000
        elif hp < 13250 and lvl == 53:
            hp=13250
        elif hp < 13500 and lvl == 54:
            hp=13500
        elif hp < 13750 and lvl == 55:
            hp=13750
        elif hp < 14000 and lvl == 56:
            hp=14000
        elif hp < 14250 and lvl == 57:
            hp=14250
        elif hp < 14500 and lvl == 58:
            hp=14500
        elif hp < 14750 and lvl == 59:
            hp=14750
        elif hp < 15000 and lvl == 60:
            hp=15000
        elif hp < 15250 and lvl == 61:
            hp=15200
        elif hp < 15500 and lvl == 62:
            hp=15500
        elif hp < 15750 and lvl == 63:
            hp=10250
        elif hp < 16700 and lvl == 64:
            hp=16000
        elif hp < 16250 and lvl == 65:
            hp=16250
        elif hp < 16500 and lvl == 66:
            hp=16500
        elif hp < 16750 and lvl == 67:
            hp=16750
        elif hp < 17000 and lvl == 68:
            hp=17000
        elif hp < 17250 and lvl == 69:
            hp=17250
        elif hp < 17500 and lvl == 70:
            hp=17500
        elif hp < 17750 and lvl == 71:
            hp=17750
        elif hp < 18250 and lvl == 72:
            hp=18250
        elif hp < 18500 and lvl == 73:
            hp=18500
        elif hp < 18750 and lvl == 74:
            hp=18750
        elif hp < 19000 and lvl == 75:
            hp=19000
        elif hp < 19250 and lvl == 76:
            hp=19250
        elif hp < 19500 and lvl == 77:
            hp=19500
        elif hp < 19750 and lvl == 78:
            hp=19750
        elif hp < 20000 and lvl == 79:
            hp=20000
        elif hp < 20250 and lvl == 80:
            hp=20250
        elif hp < 20500 and lvl == 81:
            hp=20500
        elif hp < 20750 and lvl == 82:
            hp=20750
        elif hp < 20750 and lvl == 83:
            hp=20750
        elif hp < 21000 and lvl == 84:
            hp=21000
        elif hp < 21250 and lvl == 85:
            hp=21250
        elif hp < 21500 and lvl == 86:
            hp=21500
        elif hp < 21750 and lvl == 87:
            hp=21750
        elif hp < 22000 and lvl == 88:
            hp=22000
        elif hp < 22250 and lvl == 89:
            hp=22250
        elif hp < 22500 and lvl == 90:
            hp=22500
        elif hp < 23000 and lvl == 91:
            hp=23000
        elif hp < 23250 and lvl == 92:
            hp=23250
        elif hp < 23500 and lvl == 93:
            hp=23500
        elif hp < 23750 and lvl == 94:
            hp=23750
        elif hp < 24000 and lvl == 95:
            hp=24000
        elif hp < 24250 and lvl == 96:
            hp=24250
        elif hp < 24500 and lvl == 97:
            hp=24500
        elif hp < 24750 and lvl == 98:
            hp=24750
        elif hp < 25000 and lvl == 99:
            hp=25000
        elif hp <25250 and lvl == 100:
            hp=25250
```

It's a health system based on lvl for a pokemon game (for pokecenter)
please someone give me this recoded
like this was done below

```
levels = [100, 200, 300, 400, 500]
lvl = len([x for x in levels if points > x])
```

here is the source [Level system based off points](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21519639/level-system-based-off-points)
I'm not sure how to do it.
I'm still learning python 
If you can recode it based on the example I would be greatful as I dont like this long version

Comment: Can you explain why you jump by 500 HP bewteen 90 and 91, and 250 otherwise? This makes the math marginally more annoying.

Comment: hp is level * 250. It's not that hard ;)

Comment: Psuedocode: `hp = max(hp, lvl * 250)` it seems for a long time... Why does level 91 grant 500 instead of 250 points?

Comment: hp = min(hp, 250 * lvl)   EDIT: should be max()

Comment: its a mistake thanks for pointing it out ill have to fix it @wooble

Comment: @rmartinjak looks more like `max`.

Comment: I'd recommend fixing the spelling and grammar in your post if you want this to get more attention. As it is it's going to get downvoted to oblivion

Comment: its for when u go to the poke center if your health is lower then the max per lvl then your health gets reset to the max

Comment: Wrikken, why don't you write this as an answer? ;)

Comment: @bereal indeed, I should grab a cup of coffee …

Comment: My grammar is horrible sorry

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you notice that each `hp` was 250 per level? What about

```
hp = max(hp, lvl*250)
```

Or in other words, (slower, but maybe easier to understand*)

```
if hp < (lvl*250):
    hp=(lvl*250)
```

(You could add a condition for `lvl`not to go higher that 100 if you need to.)

* Comments are there for that purpose ;)

*Edit: `max` is a builtin, so better use it:*

Comment: I like this it's very short and easy to use this also helps me since i dont have to type more to do extra lvls as i wanted it to go higher than lvl 100 +1 to Cilyan as you helped simplyfy my code to 2 lines of code

Comment: Using `max()` (as in Wrikken's comment) would be even better.

Comment: Yes, you're right. I wasn't sure it was a builtin so I checked it meanwhile. Edited. Thanks :)

Comment: thanks guys this really helped me as i had so much line of code before that it was annoying

Comment: +1 for the shorter version 1 line of code that uses max

Answer (score 0):

I dont understand the second part but for first part:

```
for x in range(1, 100):
    if hp < (250*x) and lvl == x:
            hp=(250*x)
```